# TypeError: this.props.location.state is undefined -

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a little problem with my application developed in ReactJS.
Here are my components **App.js**, **AppFront.js** and **index.js**.

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.scss';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppFront from './AppFront';
import WizardList from './wizard/WizardList';
import './App.scss';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={AppFront} />
        <Route path="/wizard/:id" component={WizardList} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AppFront.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Wizard from './wizard/Wizard';

function AppFront() {
  return (
    <div className="AppFront">
      <Wizard />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppFront;
```

In the application, I have a "Wizard" folder in which are included the components "dataWizard.js", "Wizard.jsx" and "WizardList.jsx"

[folder-structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roNOO.png)

The **"dataWizard.js"** file contains an array of objects.

```
export const dataWizard = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Harry Potter",
    category: "Gryffondor",
    text: "Harry is a powerful wizard."
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Drago Malefoy",
    category: "Serpentard",
    text: "Draco Malfoy is not very brave."
  }
```

The "Wizard.jsx" component loops on this table and transmits the properties with the  component of "react-router-dom".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { dataWizard } from './dataWizard';
import './style/Wizard.scss';


class Wizard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Wizard">
        {
          dataWizard.map((wizard, i) =>
          <Link
            to={{ pathname: `/wizard/${wizard.id}`, state: { wizard } }}
            key={i}
          >
            <span className="name">{wizard.name}</span>
            <span className="category">{wizard.category}</span>
          </Link>
          )
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Wizard;
```

I recover the properties without problem with the component "WizardList.jsx".

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style/WizardList.scss';


class Wizard extends Component {
  render() {
    const wizard = this.props.location.state.wizard;
    return (
      <div className="WizardList">
        <div className="container">
          <span className="name">{wizard.name}</span>
          <span className="category">{wizard.category}</span>
          <span className="text">{wizard.text}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Wizard;
```

Only when I reload the page, or try to access it directly by typing the path in the URL bar, an error message appears and this.props.location.state is undefined.

Here are some pictures in progressive order to help you better understand my problem.

[Homepage - number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5p9U.png)

[Information about sorcerer after click - number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbGYe.png)

[I am trying to go directly to the informative page on the sorcerer. - number 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFPG2.png)

[Error message - number 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0Qiq.png)

Please, I am a beginner, and I have tried several methods seen on the web, but I still cannot resolve this problem. Please, help-me! :)

Comment: This is a contrived example. In real applications, you will not be having `dataWizard` stored at client. So you will be fetching wizards on mount of `Wizards` component and storing it "local state" or "redux", if in "redux", `Wizard` component can retrieve data from "redux" or fetch full details of a particular wizard through an API call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WizardList gets the data to load from the location.state you are sending it in this Link

```
<Link
  to={{ pathname: `/wizard/${wizard.id}`, state: { wizard } }}
  key={i}
>
```

...but if you refresh in /wizard/:id you have nothing in location.state because you have not followed a link.
However, you have the id of the wizard in the link so you can access it with this.props.match.params.id. Then if there's something in location.state you can use it to load the page but if not, you can take the wizard id and find the proper wizard of the list.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { dataWizard } from './dataWizard';
import './style/WizardList.scss';

class Wizard extends Component {
  render() {
    const wizard = this.props.location ? this.props.location.state.wizard : dataWizard.find(wizard => wizard.id === this.props.match.params.id);
    return (
      <div className="WizardList">
        <div className="container">
          <span className="name">{wizard.name}</span>
          <span className="category">{wizard.category}</span>
          <span className="text">{wizard.text}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Wizard;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it didn't work exactly that way, but you inspired me. Here's my solution: const wizard = dataWizard.find(wizard => wizard.id === this.props.match.params.id);